# How do I get a React Native TextInput by its testID in an ios UITest

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to edit the text of a TextInput React Native component in an ios UITest. I've added the `testID` prop to the component.

Two questions:

1. Where does the testID prop appear in the native ios code?
2. How can I select the TextInput by this testID and add text to it?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput testID="username" placeholder="Enter your username" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

TestappUITests.swift

```
import XCTest

class TestappUITests: XCTestCase {

    ...

    func testExample() {
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        // Write test code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. RN uses the testID prop as the [`accessibiltiyIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification) on the ios element.

You can view it in xcode by opening the 'Debug View Hierarchy' feature in xcode and selecting the element.

[image: Using the Debug View Hierarchy to find the accessibility identifier]

2. You have to use a [XCUIElementQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/1500873-textfields) to select the TextInput component inside of an ios UITest. The TextInput is a `RCTUITextField` so you need to use the `textFields` Instance Property.

Then you can use the RN testId to select the element. From then on manipulating is easy with the [tap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618666-tap) and [typeText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500968-typetext) methods.

```
import XCTest

class TestappUITests: XCTestCase {

    ...

    func testExample() {
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()

        // Give element focus
        app.textFields["username"].tap()
        // Type text in the element
        app.textFields["username"].typeText("super-user");

    }
}
```

If you are trying to get a different type of component by testID, you can check the 'Debug View Hierarchy' to find out what type of element you have. And then work out what query you should use instead of `textFields`.

FYI, the `.otherElements` Instance Property is used to select React Native Views.