# React Native iOS UITest cannot get testID property recognized in xcode inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to add ids to react-native elements loaded in a iOS WKWebView to use on UITests but so far I always get a `<null>` as Accessibility identifier in Xcode inspector.

I followed everything as it says in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536659/4793524) comment but so far no luck.

```
    <PreventArrowNavigation >
        <div styleName='form-input' accessible={false}>
            <label styleName='form-input-label'>{localize('student_lead_welcome_nameLabel')}</label>
            <TextInput
                name='name'
                type='text'
                value={props.nameValue}
                placeholder={localize('student_lead_welcome_nameInput')}
                onChange={props.onNameChangeHandler}
                onFocus={props.onNameFocusHandler}
                onBlur={props.onNameBlurHandler}
                status={props.nameStatus}
                message={localize('student_lead_welcome_nameInput_error')}
                icons={{active: true}}
                tabIndex={1}
                testID="fullNameTextField"
                accessibilityLabel="fullNameTextField"
                disabled={props.shouldDisableWelcomeInputs}
            />
        </div>
    </PreventArrowNavigation>
```

[image: inspected element]

I also tried setting its parent element accessible={false} but it did not work.
Please help!

Comment: How are you using a div component in React Native?  Does it help to move the input outside of that component?  Also, please add the whole component code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Hi @Abe, thank you for your answer. Moving input outside div component didn't help. I'll add component code as requested.